# A comprehensive reference for RF linear accelerator's operation

Tags: particle-physics, accelerator-physics, radio-frequency

I'm doing a research on [RF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio_frequency) linear accelerators (RF Linac), but while studying the material I encountered many problems. I cannot understand the basics of the RF [linear accelerators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_particle_accelerator) in many ways, for instance

- Why the particles are accelerated in the gaps and not in the drift tubes?
- How they become in phase with the bunches of particles?
- What does bunching particles mean?

Etc.

I am reading some books but none of them has explained the principles of working in detail or with some illustrations and comprehensive figures.

- So where can I find a comprehensive resource describing the structure and operation of Rf linacs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what your level is, but I think you will find that material on accelerator structures generally requires upper division E&M. However in terms of concepts, [this overview](http://agni.phys.iit.edu/~vpa/electromagnetic.html) and [these pictures](http://agni.phys.iit.edu/~vpa/linac.html) (from Illinois Tech) will go a long way toward answering the questions you have lined out.

- In a drift-tube linac, the drift tubes sit inside a larger RF cavity and act as shields. Thus, the electric field inside a drift-tube can be approximated as zero. The gaps between drift tubes will still have an E-field, however, which varies sinusoidally in the direction of travel. When the particle is in the gap between drift tubes, it will experience an E-field and undergo acceleration.
- Let's say we are accelerating protons. We want to accelerate them in a particular direction, but half the time, the E-field in the gap is pointing in the wrong direction. Hence we can't make a continuous beam with this particular technology; we have to break the beam up into "bunches". This is by-and-large a limitation of all RF accelerating structures.

A truly comprehensive reference for Linacs is the [SLAC "Blue Book"](http://www.slac.stanford.edu/library/2MileAccelerator/2mile.htm), which is now freely available from SLAC. It is somewhat dated, but covers all aspects of building a linear accelerator in great detail. There are also a good number of SLAC publications that deal with Linacs, such as [SLAC-PUB-7802](http://www.slac.stanford.edu/pubs/slacpubs/7000/slac-pub-7802.html). You may also consult material presented by the [US Particle Accelerator School](http://uspas.fnal.gov/course-materials/by-subject.shtml). Finally, there is the RF Linac textbook by [Wangler](http://books.google.com/books?id=5EO4_nyndUMC&printsec=frontcover).